# OpenCV Sample Project Cannot Properly Shutdown

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, console

I'm following the tutorial from the official website of OpenCV:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html.

Even though I could successfully run the program, when I tried to close the console window, it took endless time to respond and the program is never closed. I had to shutdown Visual Studio, delete the exe file and rebuild the project in order to run it again.

I have even tried setting the while loop to run for a limited number of times, the result is the same.

I am just confused what might have caused the problem? Does it have something to do with the memory over-allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes the problem:

```
int c = waitKey(10);
if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
```

You should press ESC in order to terminate the program safely

Comment: Thanks and it does solve the problem. However,  sometimes (like 1 trial out of 10) the program would still hang up there even if I pressed the key and the image window had been closed. Anyway I'll accept yours as answer.

Comment: Glade it was helpful. Unconsistent behaviour is refelection of wrong code. You should debug the cases that causes this endless loop without more infornation I can not help